# PageControl backgroundColor when used in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to implement a simple tutorial using UIPageViewController in iOS7. I implement all methods in UIPageViewControllerDataSource and it gives me a UIPageControl. Everything works except that the pageControl's background is not transparent so it blocks part of the other views behind it.

I try to change the pageControl's appearance with the following code

```
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];  //works, background is green

pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //not working, background is black.
```

//updates
It turns out that the black color is the background color of the PageControl's layer. And this Page Control layer is not on top of my own ViewControllers that I used for pages. They are in parallel.So no matter how I modify its colors, I cannot get my ViewControllers to take the full screen.

Is there an easy way to move the PageControl on top of my ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the background of the parent view. I had a similar situation where the background color was actually the background of my parent control, not my own. Here is a tool I use that helped me narrow this down : http://www.sparkinspector.com. Here is another tool that does the same thing : http://revealapp.com.

Also one more thing - not sure if this would apply to your case, but it could be the background layer that might need its color set

```
CALayer *layer = self.layer;
[layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set something to be clear color, the background color then depends on whatever is on the background, the view the page control is in (usually a uipagecontrol) has no background, and this is why you're seeing it as black.